# Bug Spring Boot - jhipster - angular with one-to-one relationship

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I think I found a bug with angular, when I do a one-to-one relationship and run the project angular don't show the modal of the owner entity of the relationship.

Here is my project: https://github.com/Gerardlc/baloncestoFinal

If i implement the one-to-one relationship between "Jugador" entity and "Equipo" entity and run the project the modal of new "Jugador" doesn't shows.

Here is how I implement the onetoone in the json, then I regenerate with jhipster:entity both, clean the database and re-run.

**Jugador:**

```
{
    "relationshipId": 3,
    "relationshipName": "jugadorCapitan",
    "otherEntityName": "equipo",
    "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
    "otherEntityField": "nombre",
    "ownerSide": true,
    "otherEntityRelationshipName": "equipoCapitan"
}
```

**Equipo:**

```
{
    "relationshipId": 8,
    "relationshipName": "equipoCapitan",
    "otherEntityName": "jugador",
    "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
    "ownerSide": false,
    "otherEntityRelationshipName": "jugadorCapitan"
}
```

Any help? I think all it's ok but is so weird..

Comment: seems like that would be an issue with the Spring Boot portion of the jhipster yeoman package, since angular doesn't deal with databases or relationships at all....

Comment: So I can't do anything to solve this?

Comment: I'm sure it's fixable, but I think you are looking for a solution in the wrong place.  I would tag this as Spring Boot instead of angular so that you get better exposure in the area the problem is in.

Comment: Ok thanks, hope someone more helps